# How do tex (and latex) produce square root symbols?

Tags: tex-core, unicode, unicode-math

When you type commands like $\sqrt {x}$, $\sqrt {x^2 - y^2}$, or $\sqrt {\sum_{i=0}^n i^2}$, latex produces square root symbols, that "grow" with the size of the thing of which you are taking a square root.

My question is how does tex produce this? Does it draw the lines by itself? I have the impression that it does not do this; I believe that it draws the symbol by combining several possible unicode characters. If this is the case, which unicode symbols does it use?

I had a look and found 0x23b7 and I also found 0x221a. However I don't know if it actually uses these. In any case these can't be all, because in tex the upwards line the sqrt symbol can have at least 4 or 5 different slopes and the symbol grows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left "tick" is produced by font, either a range of characters of different size and slopes then a vertical repeatable extender, as for extending brackets. The font also specifies the width (thickness) required for the over-bar, which TeX draws in with a rule.

The variant characters for the square roots at different sizes do not correspond to different Unicode code points but will have different glyph names in the font.

For opentype fonts as used by `unicode-math`, the information is all in the MATH table which is now part of OpenType but was originally specified in this Microsoft document

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/math

In particular here: `radicalRuleThickness`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I must have misunderstood something about unicode. I thought each unicode symbol is uniquely determined by a code-point (=a hex number), but you are saying that they are specified by a code-point + a glyph name. So I should somehow figure out the glyph possible names and the possible code-points? Do you perhaps have some reference for this stuff? (I have looked in many documentations about fonts, but never saw talk about glyph names, only the unicode symbol and their numbers).

Comment: @mnr  Unicode specifies logical characters it is not (directly) related to fonts, even a font that is based on unicode may have lots of glyphs that do not correspnd to unicode code points, variants eg swash forms with exagerated italic, ligatures, parts for building extensible characters, characters that are not yet adopted by Unicode, ...

Comment: about what you say on extending brackets: There I can clearly see that in the unicode table there are a number of unicode characters that together form the brackets. For instance there is 0x23a2, aka "left square bracket extension" that you can use when drawing a left square bracket. So this I understand.

Comment: @mnr unicode "adopted" some legacy encodings some of which had character parts, so in some cases parts may have unicode slots, but many (most) extensible characters do not. Similarly for ligatures some common ligatures such as ff and fi have unicode slots but even for english there are ligatures that have no unicode number and in other languages there are many letter combinations that are constructed and have pre-made glyphs in the font but have no unicode slot.

Comment: @mnr I'll add a reference to my answer

Comment: ok thanks. I didn't know this at all. I will try to figure out now how to "access" those different forms of characters with the same unicode number. It's a bit long to explain but i am trying to make a computer program that reproduces the square root symbols from tex. I have the latin modern font in otf type, and the library I am using gives no way to access other forms of a character, all I can do is give it a unicode point and it returns me character. But I am getting off topic now. Thanks for your answer it's already very helpful to at least know that glyphs in a font do not have an id

Comment: @mnr that's a common problem (and why for instance mathjax uses modified fonts and its own javascript tables) as the standard javascript API to opentype data doesn't allow it to get the needed information from an arbitrary opentype math font