# Square root symbol from this book

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, unicode-math, math-fonts

Is there a way to use the square root symbol used in the book "Elementary Number Theory" by Edmund Landau? Check the image attached for an example.

[image]

Comment: That's the typical symbol used by the Soviet publisher Mir. I find their typography mostly good, but with several weak points: note that the radical in the first line is different from the one used later. I don't find that narrow radical particularly attractive. Also the missing space around the relation symbol is a disputable choice. Note that the font is quite narrow and the reason for it and the missing space is just to squeeze more material in a page to save money on printing.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610639/how-do-tex-and-latex-produce-square-root-symbols shows how to use an open font sqrt.  See also \surd.